# Limits are restored to the defaults after I reboot

Tags: 12.04, command-line, ram, cpu, resource-limiting

I want to remove "memorylocked" and "maxproc" limits. I am using tcsh shell. I read that if I use `#limit memorylocked unlimited` and `#limit maxproc unlimited` then they will be set to unlimited. I did that as root user. But after I restarted my computer then again they were all restored to their default values. How can I resolve this and set their values and also "openfiles" value of my Linux to unlimited permanently? I am using Ubuntu 12.04 with a 64 bit system.

Comment: Even a temporary way to unlimit them will be good too. I just found out that with temporary unlimited values, my simulation will be ok too.

Answer (score 5):

You can edit the file `/etc/security/limits.conf` as follow:

```
# memlock = memorylocked
* hard memlock unlimited

# nproc = maximum number of processes
* hard nproc unlimited
```

The first column define who the limit will be apply to:

`*` - Apply the limit to everyone, as shown in example above.

`<user name>` - Apply limit to specific user.

`@<group name>` - Apply limit to all users in specific group.

You can access the man page with [`man limits.conf`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/limits.conf.5).

Comment: This answer would be useful to even the uninitiated if you were to [edit] it to explain how

Comment: @ElderGeek Edited as suggested. I was surprised that I put in such an incomplete answer before :(